# view all reservations user has made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to view all reservations a user has made. I still require a page with all reservations available for other users of the system. I've set up another page called bookings with a controller to try and view only the users reservations. I've tried to have a look at other questions but haven't been able to solve this.

currently in my bookings controller I have

```
def index
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @reservations = Reservation.find_by_id(@user)
end
```

In my views booking index.html.erb I have

```
<h1> Viewing All Reservations </h1>


<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Vehicle ID</th>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Costs</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= reservation.id %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.vehicle_id %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.startDate %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.endDate %></td>
    <td><%= reservation.costs %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find_by` only returns one record. You should use `where`

```
def index
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  @reservations = Reservation.where(user_id: @user.id)
end
```

You could use the association records (assuming a User `has_many :reservations`.

```
def index
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  @reservations = @user.reservations
end
```

If you want the same the same method to show your reservations or all reservations, you can add a param

```
def index
  if params[:all]
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  else
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @reservations = @user.reservations
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used the 2nd solution. For some reason it's filtered it by vehicle_id rather then user_id?

Comment: I don't know your models. I cannot tell. Include relevant models (user, vehicle, registration, ...)

Comment: Sorry! just spotted it. My mistake I've labelled the table wrong. Thanks for your help!!